# Asterisk Functions in PHPAGI

Tags: asterisk

I wanted to use an Asterisk Function "IFTIME" in PHPAGI. The following syntax runs correctly in Dialplan but I have been trying to make it work in PHPAGI.

```
exten => 1234,1,Set(foo=${IFTIME(16:00-21:00,*,*,*?true:false)})

exten => 1234,2,NoOp(${foo})
```

So far in PHPAGI this is what I have done

** I am using AGISPEEDY framework, it uses PHPAGI

```
$agi->agi_exec('Set','fo o=${IFTIME(*,*,*,*?true:false)}');

$result = $agi->get_variable('foo');

$agi->verbose($result);
```

------result-------

```
Array(

    [code] => 200

    [result] => 1

    [data] => ${IFTIME(*,*,*,*?true:false)}

)
```

The above command set the function as a string. I tried changing

this: `$agi->agi_exec('Set','foo=${IFTIME(*,*,*,*?true:false)}');`

to: `$agi->set_variable('foo','${IFTIME(*,*,*,*?true:false)}');`

but result is same, it saves `${IFTIME(*,*,*,*?true:false)}` as a string.

Any help on how to run an Asterisk Function like IFTIME from PHPAGI would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have use get_full_variable if you use functions.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to fly to the moon by landing a rocket ship on Mars, what you are doing is pointless.

You are already inside a PHP script, just emulate the same check of IFTIME inside PHP. So, in your case, I will replace the agi_exec command with something like:

```
    $current_timestamp = time();
    $current_time = (int)date("Hi", $current_timestamp);
    if (($current_time > 1600) && ($current_time < 2100)) {
       .. Do some cool PHP here ..
    }
```

This segment wasn't debugged, so it may not work as you think, but you get the idea.

PHPAGI and AGI in general are wonderful tools - when used the right way. You are trying to leverage a Dialplan function/application in order to do something that you would normally do in PHP.